# How can I commit sub folder to gh-pages while keeping main project files on master?

Tags: git, github

My local files look like this:

```
.git
.gitignore
builds
gulpfile.js
```

Those files/folders are put in my master branch. I want to commit to my gh-pages only `builds/deploy` folder.

I created empty remote repository (without initializing it), then on local:

```
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
git add *
git commit -m "test"
git push origin master
```

and this is where problem started. I need to create empty gh-pages branch so I can commit only subfolder to it. First I have to make new local branch. I tried:

```
git checkout --orphan gh-pages
git add builds/deploy/*
git commit -m "test"
```

I also tried using subtree, but I got an error when trying to change local branch back to master(so I could commit all files).

I followed this guide: 
https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490
but it ommit a part where you add gh-pages branch(local) as remote branch is created automatically it seems.

I hope my question is clear enough, if not then let me know.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  In Git, generally you commit your _entire_ project with each commit, not only a folder (unless you are using something like submodules).

Comment: I want to commit whole project to git, so I can use it on my laptop. At the same time I want to use gh-pages to display my project online, but it is stored inside `builds/deploy/` folder. Should I create separate remote repository for that? I would have 2 `.git` folders in my project, one would be at the very top and other inside `builds/deploy/.git`.

Answer (score 0):

```
git commit -am "Save local changes"

git checkout -B gh-pages

git add -f builds/deploy

git commit -am "Rebuild website"

git filter-branch -f --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter builds/deploy

git push -f origin gh-pages

git checkout -
```

Found it some days ago here:
https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/dcdcab0ecc86d9643bc9c3c9a9eee8bbad63bb43/template/README.md#github-pages